# Can't save to crontab via SSH, but can when logged in locally

Tags: ssh, cron, macos-big-sur

I have a remote headless server (MacOS BigSur 11.3.1).  When I log in via ssh (with either the root user or regular user), I am unable to save to the crontab.

When I use the following command:

```
% crontab -e
```

I can see a cronjob that I saved when I was logged in locally (not via ssh).  After editing and exiting the crontab, I get the following error:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
crontab: tmp/tmp.1028: Operation not permitted
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.kKYx3tt4c1
```

While logged into ssh, I have instead tried to edit the crontab with this command:

```
% sudo crontab -e
```

To my surprise, the cronjob that I saved when logged in locally is not listed.  It is as if it is a different crontab for a different user.  In any case, I can't save to the crontab when using sudo either.  It gives the exact same error as above.

I have followed the advice of a few internet posts suggesting allowing the cron and sshd executables "Full Disk Access" through the Mac System Preferences.  However, the same error persists.

I'm not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was solved by giving sshd-keygen-wrapper full disk access.  Don't ask me why that needs it, but it is working now.  I hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue but logging in as root, over Screen Sharing, to a headless machine elsewhere in my house.  Tried giving full disk access to the Screen Sharing app just in case that helped but, it didn't.  Nor did giving full access to `cron`.  Any other ideas by chance?